# Show first div on page load and hide it when I click on another anchor

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i'm just delving into web development through the freecodecamp courses. I'm doing the first project: "the Tribute Page" and I wanted to make sort of an interactive timeline: You click a year and it shows a div of text content on what happened that year.

I've managed to find that here in Stack Overflow, but I can't seem to make the first div to show on web page load, so it's not just a blank space.

This is my code so far:

```js
$(".link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tribute-info">
  <ul id="timeline">
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1"> 1911 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2"> 1923 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3"> 1932 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4"> 1943 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5"> 1954 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content6"> 1957 </a> </li>
  </ul>
 <div class="content-container">
  <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
  <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
  <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
  <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
  <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
  <div id="content6">This is the test content for part 6</div>
  <div id="content7">This is the test content for part 7</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully my snippet can help you in some way.

have a nice day!

```js
// use this to show any content by id
$('#content1').fadeIn('slow');

$(".link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

```css
.content-container {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tribute-info">
  <ul id="timeline">
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1"> 1911 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2"> 1923 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3"> 1932 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4"> 1943 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5"> 1954 </a> </li>
   <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content6"> 1957 </a> </li>
  </ul>
   <div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
    <div id="content6">This is the test content for part 6</div>
    <div id="content7">This is the test content for part 7</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use inline style in the first div to override the css `display:none;`

```js
$(".link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.content-container div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tribute-info">
  <ul id="timeline">
    <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1"> 1911 </a> </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2"> 1923 </a> </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3"> 1932 </a> </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4"> 1943 </a> </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5"> 1954 </a> </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content6"> 1957 </a> </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1" style="display: block;">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
    <div id="content6">This is the test content for part 6</div>
    <div id="content7">This is the test content for part 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```